# How to reduce the amount of memory during parsing

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I would like to observe many websites that generate a lot of data. All this using the pupeeter library.
My idea is to run 100 containers that observe 100 pages in 5 minutes and the operation is repeated until the end of the previous one. I put it in the Docker SWARM set 100 replicas and it's all guarded that after 5 minutes I resume the observation process. SWARM is a nice solution here ... it starts containers that are watching if there is something in the queue for observation.

One such container needs 150 - 170 MB RAM. If we add everything, it comes out too many.

A separate idea is to put everything into one for loop.

```
async function run(url) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });
    var d = Date(Date.now());
    console.log("start" + d)
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://webpage.com/" + url, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    await page.waitFor(-- - 5 minutes in ms-- - );
    const html = await page.content();

    await browser.close();
    var d = Date(Date.now());
    console.log("END" + d)
}

execute_query(function() {
    for (var i = 0, len = 100; i < len; i++) {
        run(webpage[i]);
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, RAM is also coming quickly here. Can this code be optimized? Maybe I'm using the library wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a swarm of Docker containers, it might be more suitable to use a pool of browsers (or even pages). That way, there will be no memory overhead due to Docker and there will only be one Node.js script running.

You might want to check out the library [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) (disclaimer: I'm the author) which does exactly that. It can start browser (or pages) in parallel and monitor the results.

**Code Sample**

Here is an example. It launches the cluster with 100 browsers in parallel, then defines the task, which visits a URL and waits for 5min (before you want to do something else I imagine). After that, the URLs are queued. In the end, you wait until your task is finished before you close the cluster again.

```js
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

(async () => {
  // use 100 browsers
  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_BROWSER,
    maxConcurrency: 100,
  });

  // specify what should be done in each browser
  await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
    await page.goto(url);

    // do something...

    // wait for 5min
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5 * 60 * 1000));

    // do more...
  });


  // queue 100 URLs
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
    cluster.queue('http://...');
  }

  await cluster.idle();
  await cluster.close();
})();
```

Check out more examples in the [repository](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#examples). You can also queue individual tasks as well as more complex objects. I have not run 100 browsers in parallel myself, but from my experience Chrome does handle even a large number of browsers (or pages) very well. You could also try to use a different [concurrency option](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#concurrency-implementations) (to parallelize via pages instead of browser) to lower the required memory even more. Keep in mind, that you still need a lot of memory, even for 100 browsers.